# Is there an infinite number of primes constructed as in Euclid's proof?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinity

In Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes, the number 
$p_1 p_2 ... p_n + 1$
is constructed and proved to be either a prime, or a product of primes greater than $p_n$.

Trivially, we could also use the number $R_n=p_1 p_2 ... p_n - 1$ to prove the theorem, for n>2.

Intuitively, as $n$ grows, the probability that $R_n$ is prime gets smaller. Is there a proof that $R_n$ is not prime for any $n$ greater than some integer $M$ ? Or conversely, that there is an infinite number of prime $R_n$ numbers?

A possibly equivalent question:
Is there a prime number greater than $p_n$ and smaller than $R_n$ for any $n$ greater than some integer $M$ ?

Comment: Perhaps this is pedantry, but this isn't quite what Euclid's proof says. You seem to be using $p_i$ to mean "the $i$th prime", but this doesn't work: after all, if you only know $p_1, \dots, p_n$, then the number $R_n$ won't necessarily give rise to $p_{n+1}$ as a factor. Euclid does something different: he lets $\{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ be **any** finite set of primes, then constructs a new one $p_{n+1}$. Here $p_i$ simply means "the $i$th prime that we have found". Your question makes sense in spite of this, but isn't very related to Euclid's proof as it stands. :)

Comment: Euclid did indeed consider arbitrary finite sets of primes, not just the set of the smallest $n$ primes.

Comment: So I think the answer to the title question is no, the proof isn't really constructive unless you pick all the  primes. For example if you just knew that 3 and 5 were primes 3(5)+1=16 which isn't prime or the product of primes greater than ones in your list.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer to the last question is *yes*. Much more is known: there is always a prime between $p$ and $2p$, by [Bertrand's Postulate,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)
which has long been a theorem.

The numbers $P_n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n +1\:$ have been looked at quite a bit, your $R_n$, for no clear reason, somewhat less.  Very little of a general character is known about the $P_n$, and even less about the $R_n$. Prime numbers of either shape are called *primorial primes*.

It is not known whether there is an infinite number of primorial primes. More startlingly, it is not known whether an infinite number of the $P_n$ or $R_n$ are composite! There has been a great deal of computational work on these numbers, and primes do seem to become scarce among them as $n$ gets large.  You can find some information [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html)

Comment: Greetings from 2022! Trump gets elected president in 2016 unless you can stop it. I had not even thought about the idea that the composites might not be infinite which implies that at some point all larger candidates are prime. This seems like an interesting problem to work on and simpler than, say , Fermat's Last Theorem, but what do I know?

Answer (score 3):

Euclid's proof says that if there were only finitely many primes, the product of these primes +1 would be a new prime. It arrives at a contradiction.

Hence, it really makes no assertion about the product of the first $n$ primes, plus one.

Comment: Actually, "the product of these primes $+1$" is not asserted to be a new prime; it is merely asserted that this product is divisible by some prime greater than any in the initial collection.

Comment: Note the false premise. What I am saying is that were there finitely many primes, their product + 1 must be a new prime.  This is a contraction, so no assertion is made there. Only the fact that there is an infinity of primes is revealed.

Comment: That statement is false though. For instance $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 + 1$ is not prime. See the third answer here (third by votes that is): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics

Comment: Correct. there is no expectation it would be.

Comment: Maybe the proof you have in mind isn't Euclid's proof, as I'm used to it. My copy of Hardy & Wright gives Euclid's (purportedly original) proof as similar to the OP's statement: $q= 2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots p+1$ is divisible by some prime between $p$ and $q$ (here $2,3,5,\dots,p$ is the aggregate of primes up to $p$). The way I read your answer, you claim that $q$ is prime. Apparently I am misreading your answer?

Comment: Here is my proof. Suppose there is a finite collection of primes.  Let $P$ be its product.  Then $P + 1$ is relatively prime to every prime.  That is a contradiction, since we know every positive integer splits into a finite product of primes.

Comment: @Nick: He never said that the product of the first x many primes + 1 would be prime. He's saying the exact same thing as you.

Comment: @mixedmath Thanks, I gathered that from his last comment. I didn't downvote btw.

Comment: @ncm: Your proof in the comments is fine, but the "would be a new prime" in the answer is confusing. I've never seen a version of the proof that contains that assertion. In any case, Euclid's proof doesn't start with the assumption that there are only finitely many primes.

Comment: Euclid's proof was NOT by contradiction, contrary to the assertions of many respectable mathematicians who are better at mathematics than at history.  Catherine Woodgold and I wrote a paper about modern understandings and misunderstandings of this proof and how they square, or don't, with the one originally written by Euclide: "Prime Simplicity", Mathematical Intelligencer, volume 31, number 4, fall 2009, pages 44–52.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: You should not conclude that $P+1$ is relatively prime to every prime, but rather that $P+1$ is relatively prime to every member of the finite collection of primes you started with.