# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $p_1\cdot p_2\cdot...p_n+1$?

Tags: prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an infinite number of primes constructed as in Euclid's proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54679/is-there-an-infinite-number-of-primes-constructed-as-in-euclids-proof)

The question is :

> Are there infinitely many primes of the form $p_1\cdot p_2\cdot...p_n+1$? ($p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.)

For example: $2\cdot3 + 1$.

But $2\cdot5+1$ is not included in the set of primes that i want demostrate, because 2 and 5 are not primes consecutive ... sorry for my English and thanks in advance

Comment: a number of the form $p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot... \cdot p_n$ cannot be prime. Maybe you meant $p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot... \cdot p_n+1$

Comment: @Beni: Mauricio did slip up in the body, but the error in the title is not his fault. I'll fix.

Comment: yes Beni Bogosel i mean p1*p2*...*pn+1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Ribenboim](http://books.google.com/books?id=72eg8bFw40kC&pg=PA13) and [Guy](http://books.google.com/books?id=1AP2CEGxTkgC&pg=PA10) claim that it is not yet known whether there are infinitely many [primorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html) [primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html), $\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^n p_k\right)\pm 1$.