# Asymptotic results about "Euclid primes"

Tags: number-theory

Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes goes like this:

Let $p_i$ be the $i$-th prime number.

Then for every $n$, $1+\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}p_i$ is not divisible by any of the first $n$ primes, so its prime divisors must be greater than $p_n$. Thus, we have shown that for every prime, there is a larger prime.

Let $P_n$ be the **smallest prime divisor** of $1+\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}p_i$.

**Question:** Are there any interesting results on how close (asymptotically) $P_n$ is to $p_{n+1}$? For instance, is there some constant $c$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(p_{n+1}/P_n)=c$?

Comment: In some cases it should be expected that $P_n$ would be the only divisor of the listed quantity...

Comment: The product $\prod_{i\le i\le n}p_i$ is called the $n$-th [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), denoted by $p_n\#$. Its successor $p_n\#+1$ is called a [Euclid number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number). If it is prime, it’s called a [primorial prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime). It’s known neither whether infinitely many Euclid numbers are prime, nor whether infinitely many are composite, nor whether they’re all squarefree ([Is there an infinite number of primes constructed as in Euclid's proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54679), ...

Comment: ... [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number#Unsolved_problems), [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html)).


That makes it seem unlikely that there are results of the kind you’re looking for. A value $c\ne0$ would be incompatible with this state of ignorance (since the limit for the subsequence of prime Euclid numbers is $0$). The value $c=0$ could in principle be known, but this would mean that while we can’t exclude all Euclid numbers being composite, we can exclude that they have prime factors anywhere near $p_n$.